# Why is ''ValueError: image is readonly'' in PIL

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04, python-imaging-library, pixel

I want to change pixel in a grayscale pgm image. When I compile the following code it shows image is read-only. I can not change the pixel of the [image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1k5Q28nU2c7F9hDszOmxtYRjxkXyrstOt). How can I fix this error?
Here are my codes:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('Image.pgm')
pixval= img.load()
columnsize, rowsize = img.size 

img1 = Image.open('Image.pgm')
pix1 = img1.load()
for i in range(rowsize):
    for j in range(columnsize):
        pix1[j,i]=250
img1.save("share1.pgm")
```

Comment: Try `image.putpixel((j, i), 250)`

Comment: @AndreiCioara Thank you very much for your valuable answer

Comment: Glad it helped, posted it as answer. Feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to change a pixel, use the following API

```
image.putpixel((j, i), 250)
```

In particular, your code becomes

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('Image.pgm')
pixval = img.load()
columnsize, rowsize = img.size 
for i in range(rowsize):
    for j in range(columnsize):
        image.putpixel((j, i), 250)
img1.save("share1.pgm")
```

Answer (score 2):

You appear to want to use *"array notation"* to access pixels so you may find it more intuitive and faster to convert your image to a `numpy` array and do your modifications there.

So, if I start with this 320x240 black image:

[image]

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Load the image from disk
im = Image.open("image.pgm")

# Convert image to numpy array
na = np.array(im)

# Make entire image grey (128)
na[:,:] = 128

# Make pixel 1,1 white (255)
na[1,1] = 255

# Make rows 20-30 white (255)
na[20:30,:] = 255

# Make columns 80-100 black (0)
na[:,80:100] = 0

# Convert numpy array back to image and save
Image.fromarray(na).save("result.png")
```

[image]

---

You can merge the first two lines to simplify things like this:

```
# Load the image from disk and make into numpy array
na = np.array(Image.open("image.pgm"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @MarlSetcell.

Comment: Indeed this one is the way I was looking for. The useful example is another plus.

Comment: Note: If you try the same thing with np.asarray instead of np.array, you will still get a 'readonly' error: "assignment destination is read-only". This is because np.array defaults to making a copy, while np.asarray will not make a copy unless it has to.