# How to change the pixel colour of an image with PIL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'd like to change a pixel and for some reason this isn't working.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy

im = Image.open("art\\PlanetX@1.25.png")
a = numpy.asarray(im)
img = Image.fromarray(a)
pixels = img.load()
pixels[0, 0] = (255, 0, 0, 255)
```

What should happen is the top left corner of the PNG should be set as red. I get the ValueError: Image is readonly error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is ''ValueError: image is readonly'' in PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51908968/why-is-valueerror-image-is-readonly-in-pil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change just a few odd pixels, you can use the rather slow `putpixel()` like this:

```
from PIL import Image

# Create blue 30x15 image
im = Image.new('RGB',(30,15),color='blue')

# Change single pixel at 10,0 to red
im.putpixel((10,0),(255,0,0))
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can convert the entire image to a Numpy array and make many more changes, much faster with Numpy functions:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Create blue 30x15 image
im = Image.new('RGB',(30,15),color='blue')

# Convert to Numpy array
na = np.array(im)

# Change single pixel at 10,0 to green
na[0,10] = (0,255,0)

# Change whole row to red
na[3] = (255,0,0)

# Change whole column to yellow
na[:,8] = (255,255,0)

# Convert back to PIL Image and save
Image.fromarray(na).save('result.png')
```

[image]